# Changing library default folder content type

Tags: content-type, folder

I needed a folder with some additional info (lookup) so I've created a custom folder content type.

Now my question is, is it possible to set this custom content type as default for folders (so that when user clicks on "New Folder" he gets a folder of my content type)?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no out of the box method that I am aware of. Reasonably easy to do with a custom solution though.

Comment: By custom solution you mean something like a control inheriting from Listview ?

Comment: You could replace the default "New Folder" button with a custom button which than uses your custom content type instead of the default behaviour.